# Why there is a difference in the way css is applied to the modal window in Chrome and FF?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, bootstrap-modal

I was answering another question today where the modal window had clickable buttons in FF and non-clickable buttons in Chrome.

Though I have figured out the issue that chrome was setting z-index of modal's parent to `0` and FF was setting it to `auto`.

In the demo below a `modal` window is placed inside of `.fixed` div. To fix the issue I had set `z-index` of `.fixed` div more than `.modal-backdrop` (let's say 1041).
Then I thought why can't I set the z-index of `.fixed` div myself as `auto` as FF sets it to `auto`, but it still didn't work in Chrome.
Can anyone explain what's happening here.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.modal-body > span').html($('.fixed').css('z-index'));
});
```

```css
.fixed{
      position: fixed;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="fixed">
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal testing</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              z-index: <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` sets the order of elements within a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). `position:fixed` on the parent element of the modal contents places it in a different stacking context than the `.modal-backdrop`, used to hide the rest of the page.

The common solution for this is to place all the instances of modal contents from the page as direct children of the `body` element, after page loads, using this line:

```
$('.modal[role="dialog"]').appendTo('body');
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('.modal-body > span').html($('.fixed').css('z-index'));
});

$('.modal[role="dialog"]').appendTo('body');
```

```css
.fixed{
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="fixed">
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        Launch demo modal
      </button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal testing</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              z-index: <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: `.modal-backdrop` is created dynamically when we click on launch modal and removed when we close it.

Comment: What does setting z-index of parent to `auto` mean, why does the modal behave differently in FF and chrome even though I set it to `auto`.

Comment: `z-index:auto` is default. It's the same as `z-index:initial`. It works the same in both browsers. The difference is that FF does not allow stacking contexts to overlap. And they declared they are not going to change it. I updated my answer with a snippet demonstrating the commonly used fix for Twitter Bootstrap modal in FF having a `position:fixed` parent.