# Fixed position in Safari

Tags: html, css

The child fixed positioned element is not visible in Safari.

```
.parent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  height: 60%;
  overflow: auto;
  background: red;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  background: blue;
}


<div class="parent">
  Hello <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>gfgfg
  <div class="child">Close</div>
</div>
```

Is there any CSS property that can make it visible in Safari? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar problem with safari but it was on scroll the item that was supposed to be fixed was jumping like it was position absolute then snapping into place. I solved it by making the parent or child position relative. Safari seems to have trouble with nested `position:fixed`

Answer (score 6):

Try this and let me know if it helped.

add `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` to your script like this:

```
.child {
   position: fixed; 
   top: 10%; 
   right: 10%; 
   background: blue; 
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, change the child position to `absolute`;

```
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  background: blue;
}
```

You'll notice, in Safari, the element is actually there but you have `overflow` set on your `parent` div. And since the child element is `fixed`, overflow doesn't apply to it and I believe a `fixed` element within another `fixed` element still brings it out of document flow and positions it against the DOM - but still respects the parent element width.

Remove `overflow: auto` from your parent div and you'll see the child div.

Here's some more reading on nested fixed elements:
[CSS: position:fixed inside of position: fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384604/css-positionfixed-inside-of-position-fixed)

Edit:
If the child **has** to be fixed, you might have to consider changing your markup:

```css
.parent {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
}

.content {
  position: fixed;
  width: 70%;
  height: 60%;
  background: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="content">
    Hello <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>gfgfg
  </div>
  <div class="child">Close</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not an option. The child and parent both have to be fixed.

Comment: @Dipak As you can see, the `overflow` is causing this issue on Safari. I added an updated version with a markup change.

Comment: Thanks! I had this in mind but unfortunately I cannot change the markup.

Comment: @Dipak Did you get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

in your parent div if you have used, overflow: hidden. remove it. Your child will be visible. for mr it worked.